# Searching in sql, Transactions and DB File Locked

Tags: java, sqlite, javafx

I am using JavaFX with SQLite DB for making a general store management. Previously I was using SQL server as an assignment but to implement it I needed an embedded database. For that purpose I chose SQLite. Here I faced many problems as it didn't have stored procedures now I got the following 3 problems in my whole management System:

1. Error in searching through query
2. Error in executing a transaction
3. Getting error message that database file is locked.
   Now I am going to define each part separately.
   **1.Error in Searching through query**
   I was using stored procedure in SQL server for searching in a table using some text the inner query was:

   Create PROC [dbo].[spGetProductListByQuery]
   @query varchar(MAX)
   AS
   BEGIN
   SELECT p.Product_id, p.Name, pt.Type, p.Pur_Price, p.Sale_Price,   p.Stock,s.Name, s.Contact_No, s.Email
   FROM ((Product AS p
   INNER JOIN ProductType AS pt ON p.Type_Id=pt.Type_Id)
   INNER JOIN Supplier AS s ON p.Supplier_Id=s.Supplier_Id)
   WHERE p.Name LIKE @query+'%'

And in java i executed this stored procedure using following code:

```
pst=con.prepareStatement("EXEC spGetProductListByQuery @query=?");
pst.setString(1,query)
```

and it worked at that time but now as i am using SQLite studio for that purpose i am using following code:

```
sql="SELECT p.Product_id, p.Name, pt.Type, p.Pur_Price, p.Sale_Price, p.Stock,s.Name, s.PhoneNumber, s.Email\r\n" + 
                        "FROM ((Product AS p\r\n" + 
                        "INNER JOIN ProductType AS pt ON p.Type_Id=pt.Type_Id)\r\n" + 
                        "INNER JOIN Supplier AS s ON p.Supplier_Id=s.Supplier_Id)\r\n" + 
                        "WHERE p.Name LIKE ?+'%'";
                System.out.println(searchText);         
                pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
                pst.setString(1, searchText);
                rs=pst.executeQuery();
```

it works on SQLite studio but it returns nothing java, i can't understand where is the problem.
**2.Error in executing a transaction**
I have tried for so many time to execute even a single statement in transaction but it still returns error message as shown below:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO Staff (Name, Address, Contact_No,Salary,Accountant)
VALUES ('Danish', 'Gujrat','034803','22000,0)
END TRANSACTION
```

and i got following error message:

> cannot start a transaction within a transaction Unable to fetch row.

**3. Getting error message that database file is locked**
As the 3rd problem is connected to 2nd problem if it resolves I can use multiple statements in one SQL Transaction and make it possible to work. But the strange thing is that when I tried to execute this function:

```
public static Boolean saleItem(int productId, double quantity) {        
        con=Connectivity.getConnectivity();
        Connection con2 = null;
        try {
            if(productId!=0&&quantity!=0)
            pst=con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO SALE (Product_Id, Date, Quantity)\r\n" + 
                    "VALUES (?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ?)");
            pst.setInt(1, productId);
            pst.setDouble(2, quantity);
            pst.executeUpdate();
            if(!con.isClosed()) {
                con.close();
            }
            pst=con.prepareStatement("UPDATE Product\r\n" + 
                    "SET Stock=Stock-? WHERE Product_id=?");
            pst.setInt(2, productId);
            pst.setDouble(1, quantity);
            pst.executeUpdate();
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            //showErrorAlert(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }catch(NullPointerException e) {
            showErrorAlert(e.getMessage());
        }       
        return true;
    }
```

here we can see that two connections are being established at one time and it shows the error message

> org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_BUSY]  The database file is locked (database is locked)

But when I tried to execute the function having only one connection instances in which update query was executed:

```
public static void changeStock(double quantity, int id) {
        con=Connectivity.getConnectivity();
        if(quantity!=0) {
            try {
                pst=con.prepareStatement("UPDATE Product \r\n" + 
                        "SET Stock=Stock+(?) \r\n" + 
                        "WHERE Product_id=?");
                pst.setDouble(1, quantity);
                pst.setInt(2, id);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                showErrorAlert(e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

it still showed the error that is shown above.
My problems are a little long but hope so that you can help me.
Thanks

Comment: doesn't seem to be related to javafx, how is it?

Comment: I haven't seen this done before? `"INSERT INTO SALE (Product_Id, Date, Quantity)\r\n" + 
                    "VALUES (?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ?)"`

Comment: Also, If you are using another program like `SQLite Studio`, you have to close or approve changes. If you don't the program will have a lock on the DB.

Comment: actually these escape sequences are showing linebreak but it didn't matters. The matter of fact is that update query isn't executing using prepared statement. It show the error that DB file is locked. I have tried to close the connection but it still didn't works. You can see in last section from above asked question where only one connection is being established still it gives an error.